# Is $S \subset M$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $(M,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold of dimension $\ge 2$ with,  the induced metric $d(p,q)=\inf \{\ell(\gamma): \gamma \text{ is a piecewise smooth curve in M that connects p to q }\}$ for $p,q \in M$. Then for $r >0$, is $S(p,r):=\{x \in M: d(x,p) = r\}$  connected?

In the proof of the fact that "$d$ is indeed a metric", we essentially prove that the topology induced by $d$ coincides with the original topology of the Manifold (i.e. before bestowing any Riemannian metric whatsoever). Now the original topology of the Manifold is homeomorphic to the Euclidean topology by charts. Can we conclude from here? Or how to prove this?

Comment: Is $M$ connected? If not then it's easy to see $S$ need not be connected.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Thanks, of course I'm interested in connected manifolds only. I've edited.

Comment: Have you looked at _any_ examples other than Euclidean spaces...? Or at Euclidean spaces of arbitrary dimension? (::Cough:: ::cough:: _one_)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang You mean to say for $dim=1$, our very own $S^0 =\{-1,1\}$, right? Okay to avoid this lower dimensional accident, I'm editing once again!

Comment: This fails pretty badly in general, consider some arbitrary convex open subsets of Euclidean space. On the other hand, for any $x$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that this holds true for $r<\epsilon$. If the manifold is complete, this holds true away from the cut locus, but I'm not sure what can happen at the cut locus.

Comment: Look at $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ with the obvious metric $\mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \mathrm{d}t^2$, with $r > \pi$.

Comment: @Didier Note however that for each $p \in M$ we can find $\varepsilon_p >0$ such that for $0<r< \varepsilon_p$ ,  $S(p,r)$ is connected as it is a geodesic sphere.

Comment: The line gives an indication why a sphere is generally disconnected even if $(M, g)$ is complete. Didier's example shows why putting restrictions on the dimension is no help.